# Nonlinear first order differential equation general solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the equation:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}y(x)+y(x)^2=ax^2+bx+c$$
one solution is:
$$y(x)=\dfrac{1}{c_1+x}$$
Obviously, this is a trivial solution and this is what you can get from Wolfram Alpha.
What is the most general solution of this equation?
Thanks.

Comment: These equation are called [Ricatti equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)

Comment: The general solution to this equation involves (several) [parabolic cylinder functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function).  Are you sure an answer of that form is useful?

Comment: @EricTowers: this equation is related to the Benes filtering problem. In general, the $\tanh(x)$ solution is the most useful one, but, could exist mopre general solution equally useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A** way to write the general solution to the given first order inhomogeneous ordinary differential equation of Riccati type is in terms of [parabolic cylinder functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function), $D_\nu(x)$ is rational with numerator a sum of four weighted $D$ functions and denominator a sum of two weighted $D$ functions:

$$  y(x) = \\ \frac{-4 a^{3/4} C D_{\frac{b^2+4 a^{3/2}-4 a c}{8 a^{3/2}}}\left(\frac{b+2 a
   x}{\sqrt{2} a^{3/4}}\right)-\sqrt{2} (2 a x+b) D_{\frac{-b^2-4 a^{3/2}+4 a c}{8
   a^{3/2}}}\left(\frac{\mathrm{i} (b+2 a x)}{\sqrt{2} a^{3/4}}\right)+\sqrt{2} C (2 a x+b)
   D_{\frac{b^2-4 a \left(c+\sqrt{a}\right)}{8 a^{3/2}}}\left(\frac{b+2 a x}{\sqrt{2}
   a^{3/4}}\right)-4 \mathrm{i} a^{3/4} D_{\frac{4 a \left(c+\sqrt{a}\right)-b^2}{8
   a^{3/2}}}\left(\frac{\mathrm{i} (b+2 a x)}{\sqrt{2} a^{3/4}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2a}
   \left(C D_{\frac{b^2-4 a \left(c+\sqrt{a}\right)}{8 a^{3/2}}}\left(\frac{b+2 a
   x}{\sqrt{2} a^{3/4}}\right)+D_{\frac{-b^2-4 a^{3/2}+4 a c}{8 a^{3/2}}}\left(\frac{\mathrm{i}
   (b+2 a x)}{\sqrt{2} a^{3/4}}\right)\right)}  $$

Some of the complications in this expression are carefully balanced cancellations that occur when the roots of the right-hand side of the original equation are variously positive, zero, negative, or complex.  If you have constraints on those coefficients, the complications might be reduced.